# solr search query with boolean parameter

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

The following is the document I indexed into solr:

```
    <doc>
        <field name="definition">Bookshelf are to keep books. </field>
        <field name="whword">what</field>
        <field name="definitionKey">bookshelf</field>
    </doc>
```

Now I need to query this document. But my requirement is to check if both `definitionkey` and `whword` values are equals. The following is the query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/faqcore/select?q=definitionKey:bookself&whword=null&wt=json
```

Now in this query, the value of `whword` is null and this is not equal to the value in document. In this case the result should be null, but I am still getting the whole document as json in my output.

Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot add `whword=null` as a request parameter, it has to be part of either query (`q`) or filter query (`fq`).

Then, Solr does not know `null` value. You have to specify a "negative" condition, either in query or in filter query. Condition to get documents with not empty `whword` is `whword:[* TO *]` (mind the uppercase `TO`!), so any of the following should work (I skip `&wt=json` at the end of each variant):

1. `q=definitionKey:bookshelf+-whword:[*+TO+*]`
2. `q=definitionKey:bookshelf+AND+NOT+whword:[*+TO+*]`
3. `q=definitionKey:bookshelf&fq=-whword:[*+TO+*]`

Comment: server/faqcore/select?q=definitionKey:bookself&fq=whword:where&wt=json&fl=definition  worked. As i have added filter query whword:where it return empty json response since value of whword in indexed document is what.